# In ui_component products get a grid of all products for each page and filtering does not work

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, products, product-grid

[image]

In my file for ui_component:

> ```
> <dataSource name="products_listing_data_source">
>     <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
>         <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider\ProductsProvider</argument>
>         <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">products_listing_data_source</argument>
>         <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
>         <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
>         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
>             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
>                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
>                 <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
>                 <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
>                     <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
>                 </item>
>                 <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
>                     <item name="id" xsi:type="string">${ $.id }</item>
>                 </item>
>             </item>
>         </argument>
>     </argument>
> </dataSource>
> ```

In **Vendor\Module\Model\DataProvider\ProductsProvider** i get collection with all products, how i can pass value QTY per page?